# Use custom formatting within submit tag button - Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to format the text within submit_tag buttons so that I can show (for example) today's date, tomorrow, etc. I am not sure if this is possible from what I have seen in terms of general form helpers. Does anyone know if this can be done?

I have the following code in a _search.html.erb file:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :search_string, "2015-02-28" %> <%= submit_tag "Sat 28/2/15", class: "btn" %>
```

However I would like to be able to use something like strftime and a variable, for example:

```
<%= t = Time.now + 1.day %>
```

Then use the following to format the date

```
t.strftime("%a %d/ %m/ %y")
```

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
<% date = Date.today + 1 %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :search_string, date.strftime("%F") %> 
<%= submit_tag date.strftime("%a %D"), class: "btn" %>
```

Comment: This worked just perfectly. I can even see the date variable in the hidden tag needs to be "%F" format to pass back to the database table, which I would certainly have missed! Superb.

Answer (score 0):

Method `strftime` returns a string, so you can use `t.strftime("%a %d/ %m/ %y")` directly as a first argument of the `submit_tag` helper:

```
<%= submit_tag t.strftime("%a %d/ %m/ %y"), class: "btn" %>
```

I don't think assining variables in views is considered good practice though.